Laravel example app - why "could not send SSL negotiation packet: Resource temporarily unavailable" appeared
Newly installed Laravel app by composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app.
Newly created database smpro3 on PostgreSQL server. There are few another databases on this server.
Then change .env of my example-app to meet database:
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=vbulash.site
DB_PORT=101
DB_DATABASE=smpro3
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=******

These parameters checked by command line psql -h vbulash.site -p 101 -d smpro3 -U root - successful connection.
Then try to execute first migration php artisan migrate and got the following:
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not send SSL negotiation packet: Resource temporarily unavailable (Connection: pgsql, SQL: select c.relname as name, n.nspname as schema, pg_total_relation_size(c.oid) as size, obj_description(c.oid, 'pg_class') as comment from pg_class c, pg_namespace n where c.relkind in ('r', 'p') and n.oid = c.relnamespace and n.nspname not in ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') order by c.relname)

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:825
    821▕                     $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    822▕                 );
    823▕             }
    824▕
  ➜ 825▕             throw new QueryException(
    826▕                 $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    827▕             );
    828▕         }
    829▕     }

      +38 vendor frames

  39  artisan:13
      Illuminate\Foundation\Application::handleCommand()

Just clean example app. Still no swoole here!
What's up?

Have you allowed port 101 to be accessable via TCP?

For sure yes. It worked few days ago on 101 port
